# How to calculate centroids in PCA?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

To compare the centroid vectors of each group of a PCA I'm looking for a method to calculate the centroids for each PC and group. Not in particular graphical but included a plot in the MWE to make it more descriptive.

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
print(ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE))
```

Comment: check `betadisper in {vegan}`

Comment: this applied to the example above: 
`dis <- vegdist(wine.pca$x, "euclidean")`
`betadisper(dis, wine.class, type = "centroid")`
returns:
`... Average distance to centroid:  barolo 2.163 grignolino 2.954  barbera 2.396 ...`                        
which are average distances to the centroid but the aim is to get the distances of the centroids within each PC, as it is graphically shown between e.g. PC 3 and 4 by:
`plot(mod, axes = c(4,3))`

Answer (score 2):

This example provides a dataframe with the coordinates of the centroids from the PCA that then can be used to calculate distances between the centroids within the PC's

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
df.wine.x <- as.data.frame(wine.pca$x)
df.wine.x$groups <- wine.class
pca.centroids <- aggregate(df.wine.x[,1:13], list(Type = df.wine.x$groups), mean)
```

The euclidean distance between barolo and grignolino for example for the first two PC's can be calculated as follows:

```
dist(rbind(pca.centroids[pca.centroids$Type == "barolo",2:3],pca.centroids[pca.centroids$Type == "grignolino",2:3]), method = "euclidean")
```